# Crooked/uncrooked arm as sign of truth-telling. Has anyone come across this in any folklore? My example is from a Cornish folktale

Tags: folklore, superstition, british

I came across this in a Cornish folktale. Girl appears to be telling wild stories (about fairies). Wise woman tests to see if it is true: she has to crook her arm and repeat the story. If it is untrue she won't be able to unbend her arm. I've never come across this motif before: has anyone else?

It's called The Fairy Widower, and it's in the collection Botanical Tales by Lisa Schneidau, published by The History Press.

Comment: Do you happen to have any name for this tale? Or maybe an online source? Might help answerers. Welcome to mythology and folklore!

Comment: Yes - it's called The Fairy Widower, and it's in the collection Botanical Tales by Lisa Schneidau, published by The History Press.

Comment: thanks for answering! I added this info to your question. In the future it's easier to add new info to your question yourself. Comments are subject to removal and will mean information will be lost.